# Asp.NET Function, SqlDataReader IF statement not evaluating correctly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, if-statement, eval, sqldatareader

I have a function called checkTitle() that reads through a query and has an if statement with conditions based on the results returned from the Command Text. The problem is that it is not evaluating what it is reading in correctly. This function is a result of a search textbox on the page. This function is to control the databound text of a hyperlink inside of a listview. Rather than doing something like,

```
 <%#Eval("Category")%>
```

I need to be able to change it between binding to Category or Type Because in the database table, All values have a value in Category but some values in Type are NULL. So where Type is NULL I need to bind the hyperlink text to Category, if there is a value in Type I need to bind it to Type. I pass the variable Search as a query string and I am getting a value for Search when I am running through the lines of code. When I get into the while loop, It is currently reading that there are no NULL values in the database for column Type when really there should be around 7 NULL values and only 3 actual values in type. I have taken the sql4.CommandText and entered it into a separate query and works just fine, returning NULL values for Type. Here is the Code.

```
 Public Function checkTitle() As String
    Dim name As String
    Dim Search As String = Request.QueryString("Search")
    Dim Conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Sprayer_Parts_CatalogConnectionString").ConnectionString.ToString)
    Dim sql4 As New SqlCommand
    sql4.Connection = Conn
    If Not Search = "" Then
        Conn.Open()
        sql4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", Search)
        sql4.CommandText = "SELECT Category, Type FROM SubCategory  WHERE ( SubCategory.Type LIKE '%' + @Search + '%')"
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = sql4.ExecuteReader


        While reader.Read()
            Dim tst As String = reader("Category")

            If reader.IsDBNull(1) Then

                name = "Category"
                Return name
            ElseIf Not reader.IsDBNull(1) Then

                name = "Type"
                Return name
            End If
            reader.NextResult()

        End While

        Conn.Close()

    End If
End Function
```

The Markup code is

```
 <a style="color:Black; font-size:20px; font-weight:bolder;" href="Product_Type.aspx?Item=<%#Eval("Category")%>"><%# Eval(checkTitle.ToString)%></a>
```

However The Eval(checkTitle.ToString) seems to be working just find The main problem is that my reader.Read() is not evaluating in the If statements correctly.

Comment: You should put the `%`s in the parameter value, not try to add them in the SQL. Also, instead of `If Not Search = ""` you can use `If Search <> ""`.

Comment: Ok I will, Do you have any advice on why my while loop is only reading the first value returned? I will update the code above to show you. the variable tst = "test1" for every loop made, it doesn't go down to the next row. I want tst = "test2" for the 2nd loop and tst = "test3" on the 3rd loop. The string values would actually come from the sql query though

Comment: Irrespective of how many rows your reader returns only the first one will be evaluated, because of the `Return` statements. Also, you return before `Conn.Close`. So multiple connections to database will keep lying open and unnecessarily consume resources.

Comment: I commented out the Return statements and it is now cycling through all of the rows that should be returned however, I don't think it is actually breaking out of the loop now. It goes through each row multiple times and I get this error in VB. Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely. This can happen from having too many functions on the call stack or function on the stack using too much stack space.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out now how I can break out of the loop each time to actually return the value so that it can databind. If I Return outside of the loop it's only going to give me one value, either "category" or "type". I need it to return for each time through the loop as it will change each time. If I try to return anywhere inside the while loop the initial problem occurs again where it only reads the first line.

Comment: Correction if I return outside of the loop, the loop will iterate for the number of rows, Then return, then go through the loop again for the number of row. So if it is returning 8 rows it is looping a total of 64 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing away with the function to try to change the databind text and instead, just used an IF statement and inside the SELECT query I add a new column and if type is null i set the value to = "Category" if not i set it to "Type". Then I bind to the new column i created. here is the query that takes place of what i was trying to do.

```
  If Search <> "" Then
        Conn.Open()
        sql4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", Search)
        sql4.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT Category, Type FROM SubCategory  WHERE (SubCategory.Category LIKE '%' + @Search + '%')"
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = sql4.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read()
            If reader.IsDBNull(1) Then
                SqlDataSource4.SelectCommand = "SELECT DISTINCT Photos.Picture, SubCategory.Category, SubCategory.Type, CASE WHEN SubCategory.Type IS NULL THEN SubCategory.Category ELSE SubCategory.Type END AS linkText FROM SubCategory LEFT OUTER JOIN Photos ON SubCategory.Category = Photos.Type WHERE (SubCategory.Category LIKE '%' + @Search + '%')"
            Else
                SqlDataSource4.SelectCommand = "SELECT DISTINCT Photos.Picture, SubCategory.Category, SubCategory.Type, CASE WHEN SubCategory.Type IS NULL THEN SubCategory.Category ELSE SubCategory.Type END AS linkText FROM SubCategory LEFT OUTER JOIN Photos ON SubCategory.Type = Photos.Type WHERE (SubCategory.Type LIKE '%' + @Search + '%')"
            End If
        End While
```

Answer (score -1):

You're putting the result of the GetOrdinal call into a string?

Comment: The problem still persists even after changing the If statement line to

Comment: If reader.IsDBNull(1) Then.  I have figured out just now though that it appears my Reader.Read() is only Reading the first row, even though there should be around 10 rows returned from the query. I have set, Dim tst as String = reader("Category") and it's returning the same value, however the reader.Read() loop is looping through the correct number of rows.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer as this does not answer the question.